# Mechanize HTTP Error 400: Bad Request what am I doing wrong

Tags: python, mechanize

I'm currently trying upload a file to a specific webpage with mechanize and let it process the file and download it again.
But I got currently no clue, why the page is still throwing a 400 Bad Request error.
I set the user-agent, accept headers, redirects, so I got no idea why it isn't working.

My current code:

```
import mechanize
import cookielib
cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1'), 
                    ('accept', 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8'),
                    ('accept-language', 'de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3'), 
                    ('accept-encoding', '')]
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.set_cookiejar(cj)
br.set_handle_equiv(True)
br.set_handle_redirect(True)
br.set_handle_referer(True)
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.set_handle_refresh(mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time=1)           

filename = "spinner-metre.png"
url = 'http://waifu2x.udp.jp/'
br.open(url)
br.select_form(nr=0)
br.form.add_file(open(filename), 'text/plain', filename)
br.form.set_value(['2'],name='noise')
br.form.set_value(['2'],name='scale')

br.submit()
print br.read()
```

What am I doing wrong and how could I possibly fix this?